# Jenkins Build Flow plugin, unable to block a job when upstream job in progress

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to synchronize some Jenkins jobs in specific non-trivial case.

There are three jobs A B C and Z. Job Z is required to manage some hardware so its made to run on a node (There can be multiple nodes).

There are two possible build flow

1. Job-A -> Job-Z
2. Job-B -> Job-Z

   - Job-B -> Job-C

In the second build flow once job-Z is complete, Job-C is triggered. However Job-C makes use of the hardware, but it can't run on the same node that Job-Z was triggered on.

I am using build flow plugin for Job-B

```
b = build ("Job-Z", param1: "foo")
def ip = b.environment.get("TARGET_IP")
build ("Job-C", IP : ip)
```

Block upstream configuration :

[image]

This option should have blocked Job-A form triggering Job-Z when Job-B is running. However this is not working with build flow plugin.

P.S. I know build flow is depricated. Jenkins core version that I use is jenkins-core:1.651

Comment: You should be able to achieve it with this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin. You could create a category for the hardware which is shared between the jobs and require that only one job can use this category.